# Bruteforce algorithm for generating entangled states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, entanglement-entropy

Given a quantum state, we can define a few different measure of entanglement, but, at least to my knowledge, there is [not an analytical formula](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/698/1/012003/meta) for generating maximum entangled states of $n$ qubits, nor we do not know [if such formulas should exists](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06228).

What we do know however, is to check the amount of entanglement of a given state. There have been previous works that tried to "bruteforce" all the possible states up to $7$ qubits, and find the most entangled ones.

Is there a collection of algorithm for that generating at least non-bipartite state? Or any publicly available open source code? Where can I find literature on this topic?

It would be really great to have, as a common practice in science to publish along the article also the code.

Thanks.